# How to check empty value in cmd file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the command line file below. I need to check for an empty value of a variable. I am not supplying any command line arguments.

```
@echo off
@set PASSWORD=
@set PORT=9001
@set command=START
if %PASSWORD% NEQ () GOTO MyLabel

:MyLabel
@set command=%command% -p%PASSWORD%

@set command=%command% -i%PORT%
@echo %command%
```

I tried several options such as comparing with empty parentheses (`()`), empty strings (`""`), but nothing seems to work. It gives me the following output when it runs:

> () was unexpected at this time.

I am using Windows 7 x32. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
if [%PASSWORD%] NEQ [] GOTO MyLabel
```

For more info, see [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work for me. `IF [%NO_SUCH_VAR%] NEQ [] echo  Not empty` actually echoes "Not empty". Whether the variable is empty, undefined or defined and not empty, the test always returns true. Yet another weird behavior of cmd.exe?

Answer (score 12):

Use `IF DEFINED variable` without the percent signs around variable.

Tested in XP (32bit) and Win7 x64:

```
SET PASSWORD=
IF DEFINED PASSWORD (echo PASSWORD = %PASSWORD%) ELSE (echo PASSWORD is empty or undefined)
IF DEFINED USERNAME (echo USERNAME = %USERNAME%) ELSE (echo USERNAME is empty or undefined)
```